# Feature Disabled error when trying to download a Briefcase

Tags: bentley-itwin

After months of working fine, my primary test iModel no longer appears to be accessible. Was working with iModel API 2.3, but, even after upgrading to 2.18 and switching over to BriefCaseManager.downloadBriefCase, I still can't fetch the BriefCase. The error I recieve:  **Error  |imodelhub-client.iMdoelHub|  501  iModelHup.FeatureIsDisabled: Feature is disabled.**
Any insights on what I can do to get past this? I'm not seeing any options in PlantSight to enable/disable features that might be related to this

Answer (score 0):

2.18.0 version contains the fixes which address the FeatureIsDisabled error. Could you please verify that you've built your project with 2.18 version?